# Why doesn't the localization map $A \to A_f$ show that open embeddings of schemes are not always monomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, monomorphisms

Suppose $\iota: X \hookrightarrow Y$ is an open embedding of schemes. We can assume $X$ is an open subscheme of $Y$.

On the level of sets, $\iota$ is injective.

I wish to see that the pullback map $\iota^\sharp: \mathcal O_Y \to \mathcal O_Y|_X$ is injective.

I don't see how this is always true.

For example, if we take a ring $A$ which is not a domain, then the localization (restriction) map $A \to A_f$ is not always injective.

Doesn't this show that open embedding are not always monomorphisms?

If not, where is the error?

Comment: When you say "open embedding", what do you mean? If you mean "open immersion", then many standard definitions include that the pullback map $\iota^\sharp$ is actually an isomorphism. Second, you should be checking whether $\iota^\sharp$ is injective on stalks, wherein you can just use the fact that localization is transitive to see that the map on stalks induced by the morphism of schemes coming from $A\to A_f$ is the identity.

Comment: @KReiser I think “many standard definitions include that the pullback map is an isomorphism” might be a bit confusing. The map $\iota^*\mathcal{O}_Y \to \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism, but the map $\mathcal{O}_Y \to \iota_* \mathcal{O}_X$ obtained via adjunction need not be

Comment: @leibnewtz oops, I didn't see that the OP wrote it differently than is standard. But for that map it's still an isomorphism on stalks for points in the image, so their main objection is handled anyways. It might be worth adding some of this discussion to the answer?

Comment: @KReiser Okay will do!

Comment: @KReiser There are two ways to show that morphism of sheaves is a monomorphism: showing injectivity on stalks, or showing injectivity of the pullback maps.

Comment: @user46372819 Do you think I am unaware of this? As mentioned above, you're using the "wrong" pullback here. The common definition of an open immersion of locally ringed spaces is that the map on underlying sets is a homeomorphism on to an open set and the pullback map of sheaves $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\to \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @KReiser I am confident you are aware of this, but in your first comment you mentioned "you should be checking whether $i^\sharp$ is injective on stalks". I am just pointing out that we can also check this on the level of sections. I see that I was using the wrong pullback map.

Answer (score 1):

Let's recap the discussion from the comments and provide a full solution to the problem.

First, we'll fix the definition of an open immersion: a map $f:X\to Y$ is an *open immersion* of locally ringed spaces if and only if $f$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ on to an open subset of $Y$ and the pullback map $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y\to \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism (ref [01HE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01HE)). This is the standard way to talk about "the pullback morphism", and I'm emphasizing it because you apply the adjunction between $(-)^{-1}$ and $(-)_*$ to write it a different way, where the map is no longer an isomorphism but instead an isomorphism over the image of $f$ and zero elsewhere.

Next, we'll address your confusion about $A\to A_f$. In order to verify that the stalks of $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A_f}$ are the same for all points in $\operatorname{Spec} A_f$, let's remember what those points are. There is a bijection between prime ideals of $A_f$ and prime ideals of $A$ not meeting $f$, so suppose we have a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ not meeting $f$ which gives a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}_f\subset A_f$. Then the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ is $A_\mathfrak{p}$, while the stalk of $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A_f}$ at $\mathfrak{p}_f$ is $(A_f)_{\mathfrak{p}_f}$. But since localization is transitive and $f\notin \mathfrak{p}$ by assumption, $(A_f)_{\mathfrak{p}_f}\cong A_\mathfrak{p}$ and the stalks are the same as requested.

Comment: Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is an open immersion. Suppose we have two morphisms of schemes $\alpha: Z \to X$, $\beta: Z \to X$ such $f\alpha = f\beta$. We want to show that $\alpha = \beta$. We know that $f$ as a continuous map is injective, hence as continuous maps we have $\alpha = \beta$. Next, since $f\alpha = f\beta$, then $(f\alpha)_*=(f\beta)_*$. (1/3)

Comment: Therefore, the compositions $\mathcal O_Y \xrightarrow{f^\sharp} \mathcal f_*\mathcal O_X \xrightarrow{f_*(\alpha^\sharp)} f_*\alpha_*\mathcal O_Z$ and $\mathcal O_Y \xrightarrow{f^\sharp} \mathcal f_*\mathcal O_X \xrightarrow{f_*(\beta^\sharp)} f_*\alpha_*\mathcal O_Z$ are equal. Now, all we need to show is that $f_*(\alpha^\sharp) = f_*(\beta^\sharp)$. (2/3)

Comment: Any ideas on how to go about this? (3/3)

Comment: $f^\sharp$ gives an isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ and $\mathcal{O}_Y(f(U))$ for any open $U\subset X$. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer, as it seemed it didn't truly address the question. Nevertheless, I think there are some facts related to open immersions and monomorphisms that seem relevant to this situation.

In [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L1) stacks article you'll find that a morphism of $X \to Y$ of schemes is a monomorphism if and only if the diagonal morphism
$$X \longrightarrow X \times_Y X$$
is an isomorphism. Heuristically, this is saying that a morphism is a monomorphism if and only if the self-intersection of the image is the image itself. Put in this way, it should be at least intuitively clear that an open immersion is a monomorphism.

If we restrict to the category $\mathbf{Aff}$ of affine schemes, the condition that $X \to Y$ is a monomorphism may be rephrased slightly differently. Recall that there is an equivalence of categories
$$\mathbf{Rings}^{op} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Aff}$$
given by associating to a commutative unital ring its spectrum. It follows that a monomorphism $\operatorname{Spec}(B) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$
in the category of affine schemes corresponds to an $\textit{epimorphism}$
$A \longrightarrow B$ in the category of commutative unital rings. It is therefore a fact (and exercise) that any localization $A \to S^{-1}A$ is an epimorphism in $\mathbf{Rings}$.

Just a word of clarification in case it's not obvious already: while all monomorphisms of rings are injections, it is not true that all epimorphisms of rings are surjections.

Comment: If $X \to Y$ is an open immersion, then $X \times_Y X \cong X$; hence $X \to Y$ is a monomorphism?

Comment: @user46372819 That is correct. See the linked stacks project page for more details